# Cannot delete or disable breakpoint in Visual Studio 2013 Web Express

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

I can't delete breakpoint in Visual Studio 2013 Web Express:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see there is no breakpoint on the line but everytime it stopping debug on there. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try DEBUG -> Delete All Breakpoints menu option?

Comment: ctrl+shift+f9 or restart VS

Comment: I assume closing and reopening VS doesn't help? You *might* want to try rebooting, although I suspect just closing and opening it would help.

Comment: Sometimes removing `.suo` file helps. `suo` file is hidden in the same catalog where `sln` is stored.

Comment: There is no 'Delete All Breakpoints' option in Web Express Edition.

Comment: Did you try pressing F5?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+F9 worked. Thank you all guys!